# rsync left all files on Desktop listed as executable

Tags: command-line, backup, rsync

Ran `rsync` as part of a backup and noticed all files originally sitting on the Desktop were showing as type executable (green with * next to them via `ls`) in the backup location.  Is this expected behavior?

Simply copying these files via `cp` to backup location produces the same result.  Why is this and will they be accessible when I restore?

For reference, current partitioning below:
[image]

Comment: Your backup location is an NTFS or exFAT?  If so then yes this is to be expected. permissions only work as long as the files are on a POSIX compliant filesystem.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks, yes, NTFS.  so, once restored, PDFs, etc will be accessible as normal?

Comment: They will be set as executable. NEVER use windows as a backup for Linux unless you use a tarball (that one keeps permissions correctly inside it).

Comment: @Rinzwind, not sure I follow.  I ran rsync via command line/root on recovery mode (so within linux).  Is there a better way to do this (not currently able to boot into ubuntu normally).

Comment: The point of @Rinzwind 's comment is NEVER use (a Windows file system, like NTFS) as a backup for Linux... Whether the command was run within Linux is immaterial and irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I see.  Where do you suggest I backup with these partitions then (updated Q)?

Comment: Backup to a partition that has a file system supporting linux partitions. If you do not have one, make sure you obtain one. A backup should be on a separate drive, because a drive can fail, taking down your originals *and* the copy.